# Repost: Creating a RSS feed with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, rss

I asked how to do this before but it seems I needed to put more code to really get an answer.

I have a reddit type site, and I am trying to create a rss feed this is the code, but I get a Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Query failed'

Here its the code:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php'); 
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'includes/exceptions.php'); 
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'data/model.php');
require_once(SITE_ROOT.'data/comment.php');

class Article extends Model 
{
    private $id;
    private $user_id;
    private $url;
    private $title;
    private $description;
    private $ranking;
    private $points;

    function __construct($title = ' ', $description = ' ', $url = ' ', $username = ' ', $created = ' ', $modified = '') {

        $this->setId(0);
        $this->setCreated($created);
        $this->setModified($modified);
        $this->setUsername($username);
        $this->setUrl($url);
        $this->setTitle($title);
        $this->setDescription($description);
        $this->setRanking(0.0);
        $this->setPoints(0);
    }

    function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    private function setId($value){
        $this->id = $value;
    }

    function getUsername(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    function setUsername($value){
        $this->username = $value;
    }

    function getUrl(){
        return $this->url;
    }

    function setUrl($value){
        $this->url = $value;
    }

    function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function setTitle($value) {

        $this->title = $value;
    }

    function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function setDescription($value)
    {
        $this->description = $value;
    }

    function getPoints()
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

    function setPoints($value) {
        $this->points = $value;
    }

    function getRanking()
    {
        return $this->ranking;
    }

    function setRanking($value)
    {
        $this->ranking = $value;
    }

    function calculateRanking()
    {
        $created = $this->getCreated();
        $diff = $this->getTimeDifference($created, date('F d, Y h:i:s A'));
        $time = $diff['days'] * 24;
        $time += $diff['hours'];
        $time += ($diff['minutes'] / 60);
        $time += (($diff['seconds'] / 60)/60);

        $base = ($time + 2);

        if($base > 0)
        {
            $this->ranking = ($this->points - 1) / pow($base, 1.5);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->ranking = 0;
        }
        $this->save();
    }

    function vote($user,$amount=1)
    {
        if($this->has_voted($user) == false) 
        {            
            $this->points += $amount;
            $this->save();
            $this->log_vote($user); 
        }
    }

    function log_vote($user) 
    {
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "insert into votes (article_id, username) values ($this->id, '$user')";           
            $results = parent::execSql($query);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }        
    } 

    function  has_voted($user) 
    {
       try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id  = $this->id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if($results->num_rows == 1) {
                return true;                 
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }            
            parent::closeConnection($db);

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }       
    }
    function getUrlDomain()
    {
        /* We extract the domain from the URL
         * using the following regex pattern
         */

        $url = $this->getUrl();
        $matches = array(); 
        if(preg_match('/http:\/\/(.+?)\//', $url, $matches))
        {
            return $matches[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return $url;
        }
    }

    function getTimeDifference( $start, $end )
    {
        //echo "start is $start, end is $end";
        $uts['start']      =    strtotime( $start );
        $uts['end']        =    strtotime( $end );
        if( $uts['start']!==-1 && $uts['end']!==-1 )
        {
            if( $uts['end'] >= $uts['start'] )
            {
                $diff    =    $uts['end'] - $uts['start'];
                if( $days=intval((floor($diff/86400))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 86400;
                if( $hours=intval((floor($diff/3600))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 3600;
                if( $minutes=intval((floor($diff/60))) )
                    $diff = $diff % 60;
                $diff    =    intval( $diff );
                return( array('days'=>$days, 'hours'=>$hours, 'minutes'=>$minutes, 'seconds'=>$diff) );
            }
            else
            {
                echo( "Ending date/time is earlier than the start date/time");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo( "Invalid date/time data detected");
        }
        return( false );
    }

    function getElapsedDateTime()
    {
        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        $record = Article::getById($this->id);
        $created = $record->getCreated();         

        $diff = $this->getTimeDifference($created, date('F d, Y h:i:s A'));
        //$diff = $this->getTimeDifference($created, date_add(date('F d, Y h:i:s A'),new DateInterval("5H")));
        //echo 'new date is '.date('F d, Y h:i:s A');
        //print_r($diff);

        if($diff['days'] > 0 )
        {
            if($diff['days'] < 2 ) { return sprintf("%d dia", $diff['days']); }

            else return sprintf("%d dias", $diff['days']);
        }
        else if($diff['hours'] > 0 )
        {
            if($diff['hours'] < 2 ) { return sprintf("%d hora", $diff['hours']); }

            else return sprintf("%d horas", $diff['hours']);
        }
        else if($diff['minutes'] > 0 )
        {
            if($diff['minutes'] < 2 ) { return sprintf("%d minuto", $diff['minutes']); }

            else return sprintf("%d minutos", $diff['minutes']);
        }
        else
        {
            if($diff['seconds'] < 2 ) { return sprintf("%d segundo", $diff['seconds']); }

            else return sprintf("%d segundos", $diff['seconds']);
        }
    }

    function save() {

    /*
            Here we do either a create or
            update operation depending
            on the value of the id field.
            Zero means create, non-zero
            update
    */

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $this->title = addslashes($this->title);
            $this->description = addslashes($this->description);
        }

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id == 0 )
            {
                $query = 'insert into articles (modified, username, url, title, description, points )';
                $query .= " values ('$this->getModified()', '$this->username', '$this->url', '$this->title', '$this->description', $this->points)";
                createRSS(); //  ++++++ rss  +++++++
            }
            else if($this->id != 0)
            {
                $query = "update articles set modified = NOW()".", username = '$this->username', url = '$this->url', title = '".$this->title."', description = '".$this->description."', points = $this->points, ranking = $this->ranking where id = $this->id";
            }

            $lastid = parent::execSql2($query);

            if($this->id == 0 )
                $this->id = $lastid;

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }


    function delete()
    {
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id != 0)
            {                ;
                /*$comments = $this->getAllComments();
                foreach($comments as $comment)
                {
                    $comment->delete();
                }*/
                $this->deleteAllComments();
                $query = "delete from articles where id = $this->id";
            }
            parent::execSql($query);


        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    static function getAll($conditions = ' ')
    {
        /* Retrieve all the records from the
         * database according subject to
         * conditions
         */

        $db = null;
        $results = null;
        $records = array();
        $query = "select id, created, modified, username, url, title, description, points, ranking from articles $conditions";
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection(); 
            $results = parent::execSql($query);

            while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $r_id = $row['id'];
                $r_created = $row['created'];
                $r_modified = $row['modified'];

                $r_title = $row['title'];
                $r_description = $row['description'];

                if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                    $r_title = stripslashes($r_title);
                    $r_description = stripslashes($r_description);
                }

                $r_url = $row['url'];
                $r_username = $row['username'];
                $r_points = $row['points'];
                $r_ranking = $row['ranking'];

                $article = new Article($r_title, $r_description , $r_url, $r_username, $r_created, $r_modified);
                $article->id = $r_id;
                $article->points = $r_points;
                $article->ranking = $r_ranking;
                $records[] = $article;
            }
            parent::closeConnection($db);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $records;
    }

    static function getById($id)
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "select id, username, created, modified, title, url, description, points, ranking from articles where id = $id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Record not found', EX_RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
            }

            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
            parent::closeConnection($db);

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $row['title'] = stripslashes($row['title']);
                $row['description'] = stripslashes($row['description']);
            }


            $article = new Article($row['title'], $row['description'], $row['url'], $row['username'], $row['created'], $row['modified']);
            $article->id = $row['id'];
            $article->points = $row['points'];
            $article->ranking = $row['ranking']; 
            return $article;

        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    static function getNumberOfComments($id)
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        $record = null;

        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "select count(*) as 'total' from comments where article_id = $id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Comments Count Query Query Failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED);
            }

            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
            $total = $row['total'];
            parent::closeConnection($db);    

            return $total;


        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    function deleteAllComments()
    {/*
     *  Return one record from the database by its id */

        $db = null;
        try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            $query = "delete from comments where article_id = $this->id";
            $results = parent::execSQL($query);
            if(!$results) {
                throw new Exception ('Deletion Query Failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED);
            }
            parent::closeConnection($db);
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }


    function getAllComments($conditions = ' ')
    {
        /* Retrieve all the records from the
         * database according subject to
         * conditions
         */
        $conditions = "where article_id = $this->id";
        $comments = Comment::getAll($conditions);
        return $comments; 
    }


    static function getTestData($url)
    {
        $page = file_get_contents($url);

    }

}

    function createRSS() 
    {
        $articles = Article::getAll("order by created desc limit $offset, $num_items");
        $num_articles = count($articles);       

        // open a file pointer to an RSS file
        $fp = fopen ("rss.xml", "w");
        if (!$fp) {
            // Can't write to a file
            return;
            }

        fwrite ($fp, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' ?>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom=\"http://www.kiubbo.com/rss.xml\"><channel>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<title>Kiubbo.com</title>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<atom:link href='http://www.kiubbo.com/rss.xml' rel='self' type='application/rss+xml' />\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<link>http://www.kiubbo.com/</link>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<description>Todas las Noticias Fotos y Videos.</description>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<language>es-mx</language>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<docs>http://www.kiubbo.com/rss.xml</docs>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<image>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <title>Kiubbo.com</title>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <url>http://www.kiubbo.com/Logot.png</url>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <link>http://www.kiubbo.com</link>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "</image>\n");

        for($index = 0; $index < $num_articles; $index++){

        $url = $articles[$index]->getUrl();
        $title = $articles[$index]->getTitle(); // ok?


        $search = array(
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', // Strip out javascript
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si', // Strip out HTML tags
        '@([\r\n])[\s]+@', // Strip out white space
        '@&(quot|#34);@i', // Replace HTML entities
        '@&(amp|#38);@i',
        '@&(lt|#60);@i',
        '@&(gt|#62);@i',
        '@&(nbsp|#160);@i',
        '@&(iexcl|#161);@i',
        '@&(cent|#162);@i',
        '@&(pound|#163);@i',
        '@&(copy|#169);@i',
        '@&(acento|#0027);@i',
        '@&#(\d+);@e'); // evaluate as php
        $replace = array(
        '',
        '',
        '\1',
        '"',
        '&',
        '<',
        '>',
        ' ',
        'chr(161)',
        'chr(162)',
        'chr(163)',
        'chr(169)',
        'chr(\1)');

        $content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
        $title = preg_replace("/&/", 'y', $title);
        $content = preg_replace("/&/", 'y', $content);

        fwrite ($fp, "<item>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <title>$title</title>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <link>$url</link>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<guid>http://www.kiubbo.com</guid>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "</item>\n");
        }
        fwrite ($fp, "</channel></rss>\n");
        fclose ($fp);
    }

?>
```

Thx

Regards
Carlos

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you have any idea of which function generate the error? Also you should use prepared statements for you queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at a machine with php to test this, but you have queries with variables as follows...

```
"select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id  = $this->id"
```

I'm fairly certain that you need to bracket or concatenate when using objects...

```
"select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id  = ${this->id}"
```

or

```
"select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id  = " . $this->id
```

Comment: may i note that the variables used in the query are NOT checked/parsed anywhere to ensure no sql injection or other bad things can happen?

Comment: @giorgio - It's not clear from the question whether or not the developer is sanitizing the input, so the answer gave the benefit of the doubt to the developer. That said, it's such a common mistake that it's a useful warning.

Comment: i was not commenting on your anwer (which is correct and helpfull!) but on the poster himself. As you can see the data used is inserted either via the constructor, or the setters. The constructor uses the setters too (which is a good thing!), but the setters do nothing more than just copy the vars. his parent method `execSQL` cannot sanitize the vars explicitly (or it should be a REALLY smart sanitizer, which i have not encountered before), so this makes it clear the input is not sanitized at all. To the poster; do something about it! What about a `mysql_real_escape()` in the setters?

Comment: I guess I was thinking the poster may have sanitizing helpers that are used in the page part of the code. But by putting the sanitizer into the class, there is less need to rely on page sanitation, less repitition, and at a low overhead cost (in cases where the data isn't coming from the user, but the db or some other "safe" source). So I would agree with the suggestion.