# Error in MySQL update command. (in php)

Tags: php, mysql

Good Morning everyone,

I am using an update command in php to update data in mysql. This is my code:

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE blpublication SET JournalName = '$_POST[journal]', AcceptanceDate = '$_POST[acceptancedate]', PublishedDate = '$_POST[publisheddate]', Comment = '$_POST[comment]'
WHERE JobNo = '$_POST[jobno]'");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "record Updated";
```

It does updates the field but, it gives me the following error. And i can not figure it out why am i getting this error. 
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1"

Can you help me in this

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: Do a "echo $sql;" before sending the query to the MySQL server to check what actually is being sent to the server.
Also please note that you should NEVER put user input directly into a SQL query (aka. "SQL injection") - always filter, validate and/or sanitize the user input!

Comment: my lord. it's an sql injection hack just waiting to happen.

Comment: Quite weird that no one suggested a prepared statement instead of escaping input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you tell us what the exactly output of `$sql` is? By the way, **BIG** security hole there. You should **always** escape query inputs namely:

```
$journal = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['journal']);
$acceptance_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acceptancedate']);
$publish_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['publisheddate']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$job_no = intval($_POST['jobno']); // assuming jobNo is a number
$sql = <<<END
UPDATE blpublication
SET JournalName = '$journal',
AcceptanceDate = '$acceptance_date',
PublishedDate = '$publish_date',
Comment = '$comment'
WHERE JobNo = $jobno
END;
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_error()) {
  die("Error executing query '$sql': " . mysql_error());
}
echo "record Updated";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would sanitize your input first. This could lead to some very nasty errors such as what you are experincing and malicious attacks. Look up [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're running mysql_query twice. The first time it works and returns 1 (true), which you assign to $sql. Then you call mysql_query again, passing $sql (which equals 1). Of course "1" is not a valid SQL query, so you get the syntax error.

I wholeheartedly agree that you must sanitize those inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870160/repost-creating-a-rss-feed-with-php/870286#870286), i believe when you have any object or array syntax, you need to put in braces.

```
SET JournalName = '${_POST[journal]}'
```

edit: and yes, as others pointed out you are risking sql injection.

Comment: Ummmm... wrong language? There is no SET in PHP. And you can as well use it without braces.

Comment: @soulmerge - the SET is within the SQL query.

Comment: @soulmerge as Eli said, I clipped the example to just show an example of my explanation

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/), escape your POST values:

```
$journal = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['journal']);
```

And to actually debug your query, we need the query itself. Add an echo() statement before the actual execution of the query and post the result, the POST values possibly contain some unexpected value.

Comment: Better yet: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your general UPDATE syntax looks ok, except for the obvious injection possibilities, but you need to output $sql.  One of your variables probably has a quote in it or some other issue like that....

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SQL `UPDATE` statement in your code, one thing leaps out at me. The table name is `blpublication`, are you maybe missing a 't', i.e. `tblpublication`?

Also you should really sanitise your input, otherwise you're going to be a victim of a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you. i did sanitize my input. and it works well now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the $_POST values. Im not sure if including them without quoting the key is possible?

```
$sql= mysql_real_escape_string("UPDATE blpublication SET JournalName = '".$_POST['journal']."', AcceptanceDate = '".$_POST['acceptancedate']."', PublishedDate = '".$_POST['publisheddate']."', Comment = '".$_POST['comment']."'
WHERE JobNo = '".$_POST['jobno']."'");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: mysql_* commands are depreciated. You should switch over to [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).